# visual basic in excel : Find subfolder and open it with specific string (cell value) in main directory

Tags: vba

I am using this script to find a sub-folder with a specific string (in this case 300) in the main directorys main path.

```
Sub Find_SubFolder()
Dim sFile As String, sPathSeek As String, sPathMatch As String

Const sMainPath As String = "C:\Users\502158766\Desktop\testje\"

On Error Resume Next
sPathSeek = sMainPath & 300 & " " & "*"
sFile = Dir(sPathSeek, vbDirectory)

Do While Len(sFile) > 0
    If Left(sFile, 1) <> "." Then
        If (GetAttr(sFile) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
            sPathMatch = sFile
            Exit Do
        End If
    End If
    sFile = Dir
Loop

MsgBox IIf(sPathMatch = "", "Match not found", "Found in: " & sMainPath & sPathMatch)
Call Shell("explorer.exe " & sMainPath & sPathMatch, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

I am looking for an upgrade of this script allowing to check every sub-folder starting from the main directory to do the same (search and open folder which contains 300)
Furthermore the script should open the highest sub-folder in line.

For example : 
My main directory holds the following maps :

```
C:\Users\502158766\Desktop\testje\fruit\apples\30 greens\30 fromENG

C:\Users\502158766\Desktop\testje\fruit\apples\30 greens\30 fromUSA

C:\Users\502158766\Desktop\testje\fruit\apples\30 greens\30 fromBELG

C:\Users\502158766\Desktop\testje\fruit\apples\30 greens\30 fromNL

C:\Users\502158766\Desktop\testje\fruit\apples\30 greens\30 fromCYP

C:\Users\502158766\Desktop\testje\fruit\banana\15 greens\15 fromENG

C:\Users\502158766\Desktop\testje\fruit\banana\15 greens\15 fromUSA

C:\Users\502158766\Desktop\testje\fruit\banana\10 greens\15 fromBELG

C:\Users\502158766\Desktop\testje\fruit\banana\20 greens\15 fromNL

C:\Users\502158766\Desktop\testje\fruit\banana\50 greens\15 fromCYP
```

The script should now open the 30 greens map in case 30 is in path-seek. And in case 15 is in path-seek, it should open the 15 greens map and not the others.

I've been trying yesterday and I found a way to open all folders in the main directory and use a combination of text to column follow the hyper-link to the highest sub-folder. However it's been a real hassle with the script crashing due to many files.

Hope my question is clear,
Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: have a look in [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461935/vba-macro-to-mass-update-multiple-files-in-same-location/17470628#17470628)

Comment: I can understand you are using this option in a part of your script (which is very nice btw). However, I am afraid I don't have the knowledge to adjust it to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/650268-excel-visual-basic-applications-get-full-folder-name-folder-path-wildcard.html) . It almost works. I think you'll need to add the apth to SFile when calling "GetAttr(sFile)"